# graphic of $(-2)^x$, domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a little bit confused with the graphic of $f(x) =(-2)^x$

I know that is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ when $x = \frac{n}{2k}$, where $n, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I have found a lot of different values of $x$ where I can no define it.

Please could you help me to have a general rule and an idea of how will look its graphic

how is its domain and range?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Irrational powers are defined only for positive numbers. That's not laziness, there is a very precise reason:

$a^x = e^{\log a^x} = e^{x \log a}$

and as you may recall, the logarithm is defined only for positive values.